# Proving {$b_n$}$_{(n=1)}^\infty$ converges given {$a_n$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and {$a_n + b_n$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose {$a_n$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ {$b_n$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are sequences such that {$a_n$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and {$a_n + b_n$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge.  Prove that {$b_n$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ also converges.

I'm confused on a few parts.  Taking what can be assumed, we know that for every $\epsilon$>0, there exists $N_1 \in \Bbb N$ such that for every n $\in \Bbb N$, if n$\ge$$N_1$, then |$a_n -A|\lt \epsilon$.  Also, we know that for every $\epsilon$>0, there exists $N_2 \in \Bbb N$ such that for every n $\in \Bbb N$, if n$\ge$$N_2$, then |$a_n + b_n - (A+B)|\lt \epsilon$.

How would you put the two of these together in order to form a proof that {$b_n$}$_{(n=1)}^\infty$ converges too?

Please don't write a proof for the answer. Just give arguments that will help lead me on the path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** If $a_n\to a$ then $-a_n\to-a$. Show that $(a_n+b_n)+(-a_n)$ is the sum of two convergent sequences and so it converges as well.

Comment: Is this the idea you're saying?

{$a_n$}$_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to A; 

{$a_n + b_n$}$_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to .

Thus, 
($a_n + b_n$) + ($-a_n$) $\to$ C - A.

And from here use the definition of convergence to show then {$b_n$} must also converge?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that if $a_n\to a$ and $b_n \to b$, $a_n - b_n \to a - b$.

Comment: how can you use $b_n$ converges to b if it isn't something that can be assumed from the hypothesis.

Comment: Apply this to the sequences $a$ and $a + b$.